# How to get a unique value in a row for different list of values?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

This is the query I have written:

```sql
select c.id, CONCAT(c.major_version, '.', c.minor_version) as versions
from event_ids c
where c_id in ('101') group by c_id, major_version, minor_version;
```

This is the result I am getting

| id | versions |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 0.0 |
| 101 | 1.0 |
| 101 | 2.0 |
| 101 | 3.0 |

I am trying to get a single value against a list of different values for the same id.

| id | versions |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 0.0 |
|  | 1.0 |
|  | 2.0 |
|  | 3.0 |

How do I write the query so I get the desired result?

Comment: This is better done in your application when you _display_ the result. SQL isn't designed for things like that. (And why are you storing numbers as strings?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select (case when rowNumber = 1 then c_id else null end) id, versions 
from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY c.c_id ORDER BY major_version) as rowNumber, c.c_id, 
        CONCAT(c.major_version, '.', c.minor_version) as versions
    from event_ids c
    where c_id in ('101') group by c_id, major_version, minor_version
) tempTable
```

Comment: Can you suggest which data structure would be correct to store the desired result?

Comment: Maybe `bigint` because id is primary key

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
select case when c.major_version = 0 and c.minor_version = 0 then c.id else null 
end as id, 
CONCAT(c.major_version, '.', c.minor_version) as versions
from event_ids c
where c_id in ('101') group by c_id, major_version, minor_version;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).